# Why cant I use fftw3 with cmake

Tags: c, cmake, dll, mingw, fftw

I want to use fftw3 in a project, I am already using CMake in the project so I am trying to include the fftw3 library with CMake, I already modified my CMakeLists file to include fftw3 in my main source code I can include the library with no problems but when I try to use fftw_malloc() and use mingw32-make in the build directory it gives me an error:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__fftw_malloc'
```

this is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(myproj)

add_subdirectory(raylib)

include_directories(fftw3)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)

find_library(FFTW3_LIB fftw3 PATHS "fftw3")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} raylib ${FFTW3_LIB})
```

I was using raylib with cmake for the project thats with I want to use CMake for fftw3 too, the raylib source has a CMakeLists.txt file already so its easy to include it.

These are the files I have in my fft3 directory:

```
    bench.exe
    benchf.exe
    benchl.exe
    fftw-wisdom.exe
    fftw3.f
    fftw3.f03
    fftw3.h
    fftw3l.f03
    fftw3q.f03
    fftwf-wisdom.exe
    fftwl-wisdom.exe
    libfftw3-3.def
    libfftw3-3.dll
    libfftw3f-3.def
    libfftw3f-3.dll
    libfftw3l-3.def
    libfftw3l-3.dll
```

fftw3 directory has a the header file for fftw3 and it has the dll and def files

I am kinda new to CMake so I dont know if this is correct.

Comment: maybe cmake didnt actually find your fftw3. after your `find_library` statement, add a `message` that prints the value of `FTW3_LIB`. also, build your project verbosely so you can see what the individual steps are. if you were on "unix" and using `make` you'd do `make myproj VERBOSE=1`. look for the link command and see if it's what you'd expect

Comment: When I print the value of message FFTW3_LIB I get "projectname/build/fftw3/libfftw3.a", I can do mingw32-make VERBOSE=1 but I am not that experienced with C and linking libraries so I cant find the problem by using verbose mode

Comment: I deleted the build directory and remade it and now It says FFTW3_LIB is NOTFOUND